# More terse form of "the topic of which was"

Tags: abbreviations, prepositional-phrases

I'm looking for a phrase to replace *the topic of which was*, with the goal of brevity. For example, could something like

> The novel, **the topic of which was** whaling, proved to be excellent
>   reference material for my upcoming whaling expedition

be reduced somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'The novel, which was about whaling . . .'

Comment: +1 Also "on", "regarding", and "concerning".

Answer (score 1):

You can write

> The novel, **whose topic was whaling**, proved to be excellent reference
>   material for my upcoming whaling expedition.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the verb "to pertain".

*The novel pertaining to whaling proved to be excellent reference material for my upcoming whaling expedition.*

Alternatively, why not just use "about"?

*The novel about whaling proved to be an excellent reference material for my upcoming whaling expedition.*

Merriam-Webster: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pertain

Answer (score 0):

> The novel, the topic of which was whaling, proved to be excellent reference material for my upcoming whaling expedition.

Terms *whaling-centered* and  *whaling-related* are worth considering.  If they are used, the second occurrence of *whaling* might be left out.  For example:

> The whaling-centered novel provided excellent reference material for my expedition.